# Which Oracle SQL query optimization tool to use?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

Yesterday I read an article in PowerTimes ( dec. 2002 :) ) about a great SQL Optimization tool called SQL Expert created by Leccotech. This company is probably taken over by Quest Software and I faced a lot of bugs in the trial version of Quest SQL Optimizer 8.0.0.

Which software do you prefer to optimize your Oracle ( 10 or 11 ) SQL queries?

Regards,
Marinus

Comment: dbForge Studio for Oracle is a powerful oracle query optimization tool with abilities to get query execution plan, session statistics, etc.

You can [optimize sql queries](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/) also in dbForge Studio for Oracle. It has full functionality in 30-day trial version.

Answer (score 3):

I too use explain plan (and a decent grasp on [Oracle Concepts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/toc.htm) and the [optimizer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/toc.htm)), but I'll also mention that Oracle develops a [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) IDE that is getting more advanced than when I first used it.

SQL Developer now has a [SQL tuning advisor](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/sqldev/tuningadvisor/tuningadvisor_viewlet_swf.html) that is worth checking out.  I have not yet used the latest version, but will be doing so soon.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I use EXPLAIN PLAN with the SQL client of my choice

Answer (score 1):

I also use the explain plan.

The best method to tune a query is to know as much about what it's purpose is and what it is doing.

Learn about the tables, indexes, constraints, data most importantly, and how the CBO (or RBO) is going to retrieve the data.

You can use software to point and click your way through, but if you don't know yourself what the query and oracle is doing, you won't get very far.